# Gradient text with css selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this structure of code. I want to apply gradient on 3 letters but it applies separately. That is not looking good. I don't want to change the structure because I used this in animation.

```css
.gradient-text {
  font-size: 24px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  display: inline-block; 
}

.gradient-text div {
  display: inline; 
  color: black; 
}

.gradient-text div:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6) span {
  /* Targets letters L to B */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-text">
  <div><span>A</span></div>
  <div><span>P</span></div>
  <div><span>P</span></div>
  <div><span>L</span></div> <!-- Start of the range -->
  <div><span>E</span></div>
  <div><span>B</span></div> <!-- End of the range -->
  <div><span>A</span></div>
  <div><span>L</span></div>
  <div><span>L</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What effect are you looking for because if the linear-gradient is continuous behind those three letters the L looks basically red, just a little tinge on the right, the middle looks basically mauveish and the right looks basically blue at a glance. The effect of the linear-gradient isn't really enough to make a difference between that and solid colors on each letter.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. If keeping the same amount of `<div>` and `<span>` is important for the animation of your css, you could apply three separate smaller gradients to each individual letter.

   ```css
   .gradient-text {
     font-size: 24px; 
     font-weight: bold; 
     display: inline-block; 
   }

   .gradient-text div {
     display: inline; 
     color: black; 
   }

   .gradient-text #letterL {
     background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, #4d00b2);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     color: transparent;
   }
   .gradient-text #letterE {
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #4d00b2, #92006d);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     color: transparent;
   }
   .gradient-text #letterB {
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #92006d, red);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     color: transparent;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="gradient-text">
     <div><span>A</span></div>
     <div><span>P</span></div>
     <div><span>P</span></div>
     <div><span id="letterL">L</span></div> <!-- Start of the range -->
     <div><span id="letterE">E</span></div>
     <div><span id="letterB">B</span></div> <!-- End of the range -->
     <div><span>A</span></div>
     <div><span>L</span></div>
     <div><span>L</span></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. If you can combine the letters into the same affected element, the gradient will apply across all letters in that element.

2a) Using the existing `<div>`, `<span>`, and gradient:

```css
.gradient-text {
  font-size: 24px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  display: inline-block; 
}

.gradient-text div {
  display: inline; 
  color: black; 
}

.gradient-text div:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+4) span {
  /* Targets letters L to B */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-text">
  <div><span>A</span></div>
  <div><span>P</span></div>
  <div><span>P</span></div>
  <div><span>L E B</span></div> <!-- Range: 4th-4th child (just this one) -->
  <div><span>A</span></div> 
  <div><span>L</span></div>
  <div><span>L</span></div>
</div>
```

2b) Adding a wrapper and using `background-image`:

```css
.gradient-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gradient-text div {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
}

.gradient-text #gradient >* {
  /* Targets letters L to B */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: 10%;
  background-position: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-text">
  <div><span>A</span></div>
  <div><span>P</span></div>
  <div><span>P</span></div>
  <div id="gradient">
    <div><span>L</span></div> <!-- Start of the range -->
    <div><span>E</span></div>
    <div><span>B</span></div> <!-- End of the range -->
  </div>
  <div><span>A</span></div>
  <div><span>L</span></div>
  <div><span>L</span></div>
</div>
```